# react native performance in long flastlists

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to convert an objective c app to react native, I have a list which is composed of 328 items, react native rendering is slow as hell.
I'm using Flatlist with a custom row object, this custom row object is just a view showing two lines of text (I was hoping to add an image at some point). I read about some possible optimizations, and I think I saw them all :

- declaring the row item as a PureComponent.
- telling my Flatlist that there is actually 328 component and it won't change.
- telling the Flatlist how it can compute the height of the nth element

I suppose that the release would also work better, but I'm still trying/debugging things.

1) how can I make things better ?

2) if there is no way : can I use an objective c object to render the items of the list ? it kinda kills the whole javacript thing, but I suppose it would render faster.

3) Are images cached ? I mean the objective c way is to have a NSDictionnary of images and download them if they're not in it. I'd like to do something like that with react native, do I have to do it explicitly or are the images cached ?

Comment: Regarding images cache - this is platform-specific, but the short answer is yes, by default they are cached. There are options for ios, though, feel free to check http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/images.html#cache-control-ios-only

Comment: just in case, maybe check the render of list items and if it happens multiple times, try applying `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: FYI u cant get performance on debug mode. try a release mode build. I have rendered around 2000 items in flatlist, It works smooth

Comment: **dhorelik**: I didn't implement shouldComponentUpdate, I thought implementing this function was the only way to make a PureComponent update. In my case, I will never update a list Item, do I really have to implement this function returning false everytime ?
**Vicky**, I probably should have tried before asking  this question, I will try it, but I confess I haven't even look at how to make a release right now ^^'